# Are "identify this prop" questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions asking for the identification of a prop from a movie or TV show on topic here? I ask because there's no [identify-this-prop](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-prop) tag and I immediately received a down vote upon asking this question, [What brand of TV's were used to display Tony Montana's security cameras?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/55356/36651).

---

Here are a few examples of questions that already exist:

- [What kind of flashlights are used in the X-Files by the
  FBI?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/19119/36651)
- [What kind of glasses is Ronnie Kray
  wearing?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/36215/36651)
- [What type of keyboard does Caden Cotard
  using?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/55333/36651)

What is the consensus on this?

Comment: Related (if not even duplicate): [Are we here to identify the random stuff that people use in films or TV shows?](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2119/49)